# spring security - jwt request filter validates and authenticate session but principal is null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

After updating my spring boot from `2.0.3` to `2.2.1` somehow my `Spring Security` configuration stop working.
setup is as follow - I would like to have all my request processed by request filter where `JWT` token is validated and `UserDetails` are created. So config is pretty easy:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class NoAuthConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();


    }
}
```

and filter class

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtRequestFilter.class);

    @Autowired
    private JwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private JwtUtils jwtTokenUtil;
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String requestTokenHeader = "";
        try{
            requestTokenHeader = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "token").getValue();
        } catch (NullPointerException ex ){}
        if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.contains(".")) {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader;
            try {
                username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                log.error("Unable to get JWT Token");
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                log.error("JWT Token has expired");
            }
        }  
        if (username != null ) {
            UserDetails userDetails = null;
            userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                    usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                            .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        } else {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
            return;
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);

    }
    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
                "/v2/auth/",
                "/api/packetdiscovery"
        };
        String path = request.getServletPath();
        return (StringUtils.startsWithAny(path, AUTH_WHITELIST));
    }
}
```

and by debugging I can see that everything work smoothly until request reach Controller where `NullPointerException` Is thrown on `Principal`

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')")
@GetMapping(value = "/userinfo")
public ResponseEntity<SessionOwner> getSesstionOwner(Principal user) {
    return dashboardService.getSessionOwner(user.getName());

}
```

Could anyone give me advice on how to handle it?